# Combine model's condition with its association's condition in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

Is there a way to find models by a condition that applies to its own field *or* to its association's field?

Given models `Model` and `Association`, where each `Model` has one `Association`.

```
const Model = sequelize.define('model', {
    name: sequelize.STRING,
});

const Association = sequelize.define('association', {
    name: sequelize.STRING,
});

Association.belongsTo(Model);
Model.hasOne(Association);
```

I want to find all `Model`s, that either has a `name` equal to "text", *or* has an `Association` with a `name` equal to "text".

So far I come up with the solution with `Sequelize.literal`, that doesn't look robust enough.

```
Model.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    include: [{
        model: Association,
        attributes: [],
    }],
    where: {
        $or: [
            { name: 'test' },
            Sequelize.literal('association.name = \'test\''),
        ],
    },
});
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is described in the docs: [Top level where with eagerly loaded models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models).

```
Model.findAll({
    attributes: ['id', 'name'],
    include: [{
        model: Association,
        attributes: [],
    }],
    where: {
        $or: [
            { name: 'test' },
            { '$association.name$':  'test' },
        ],
    },
});
```